# samba 'homes' share works, raid doesn't [fedora 17 to windows 7]

Tags: windows-7, samba, fedora-17

I have a basic LAN at home, and am trying to share a raid drive mounted on my Fedora 17 machine to Windows 7 via samba.

I can browse to my home directory (ie: through the `homes` share), but not to the raid drive.

Here is a dump from my log:

```
$ cat /var/log/samba/log.steve-pc
[2013/02/21 20:49:01.512517,  0] smbd/service.c:1055(make_connection_snum)
  canonicalize_connect_path failed for service raid, path /mnt/raid
```

Here is my samba version:

```
$ smbd -V
Version 3.6.12-1.fc17
```

I have the following in my `/etc/samba/smb.conf`:

```
[global]
  workgroup = WORKGROUP
  server string = NAS samba server %v

  security = user
  passdb backend = tdbsam

[homes]
  comment = Home Directories
  browseable = yes
  writable = yes

[raid]
  path = /mnt/raid/
  public = yes
  writable = yes
  browseable = yes
  available = yes
  create mask = 0777
  directory mask = 0777
```

My Windows 7 workgroup is `WORKGROUP`.

User, group and permissions I believe are correct?

```
$ ls -l /home
drwx------. 33 steve steve  4096 Jan 31 19:39 steve

$ ls -l /mnt 
drwxrwxrwx. 16 steve steve 4096 Jan 28 18:36 raid
```

The raid mount is working - I can browse in Fedora and mount via NFS to other Linux machines. In case it's useful, here are the details from my `/etc/fstab`:

```
# raid
/dev/md/NAS:0      /mnt/raid     ext4    defaults    1 2
```

I have created a samba user, and authenticated from windows.

If I browse to `\\nas` I can see `homes` and `raid` listed.

If I browse to `\\nas\homes` I can browse through my home directory, access files etc.

Attempting to browse to `\\nas\raid` fails though. It eventually times out saying `Windows cannot access \\nas\raid`.

- I know my firewall isn't an issue since I can get through to my linux home directory.
- I know authentication isn't an issue for the same reason.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was not samba itself, it was selinux preventing access to samba

Details here:

http://linux.die.net/man/8/samba_selinux